# Cannot download files using Google Drive API in Go

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I am trying to download some *.FIT files using Google Drive API for Go, from a private folder stored in my Google Drive. (Garmin 310XT data)

I have followed the wizard and guide found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/go), and have successfully obtained a full list of files from a folder by id.

I am using [this sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get), but I cannot download any of the files.
Both the file DownloadUrl and the ExportFormats properties are always empty.
Has anyone successfully done this, or am I just missing something important?

Edit:
The first problem was about scope, but after changing it to drive.DriveScope I can only download 0 byte files.

---

#### Solved

Using the correct http.RoundTripper solved the 0 byte size issue.
(client.Transport)

Comment: define cant download the file.

Comment: As mentioned, both the file DownloadUrl and the ExportFormats properties are always empty.

Comment: what scope did you authenticate with?

Comment: I used this example code for authorization https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/go under the same user account (mine) which was used for uploading the files. (From an android app)

Comment: What I meant was authentication. :-)

Comment: OK my GO skills are beyond nub range.  but ..  drive.DriveMetadataReadonlyScope  is probably your problem  see if you can find something like drive.DriveScope or drive.DriveFileScope   (I am guessing here) check this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: I'm no a GO guy, but I just answered something similar in Java, see  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250924/unable-to-download-file-from-google-drive-using-java-api/33276864#33276864). You may try to translate it to GO.

Comment: Ahhh, @DaImTo - You might be on to something there :-) The app has View Metadata. Now I just need to figure out how to change this. I will test when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Yup viewmeta data wont let you download the file.  Up the scope and reauthentcate try again.

Comment: ... and another version of the same problem (in Java again) is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279687/download-google-docs-file-from-google-drive-with-java/33280384#33280384).

Answer (score 1):

Is the file restricted?

See [files docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) under `labels.restricted`

`labels.restricted`     `boolean`   Whether viewers and commenters are prevented from downloading, printing, and copying this file.

Comment: No, the files are not restricted. Values: {Hidden:false Restricted:false Starred:false Trashed:false Viewed:true}