# Download Google Docs file from Google Drive with java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file from Google Drive. Download of a common file (pdf, jpg) went without any problem. But I can't get it to download Google files. I am getting an empty file without type and with size 0. Do you have any idea of what might cause this?

```
public InputStream download(String id) throws CloudServiceException {
    try {
        File file = service.files()
                .get(id)
                .execute();
        String link = file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf");
        HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
                .buildGetRequest(
                        new GenericUrl(link))
                .execute();
        return resp.getContent();
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        throw CloudServiceExceptionTransformer.transform(e, e.getStatusCode());
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new InternalException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in fact in building of a response. Google files have a size 0 and google media type was not recognized which resulted in this broken file.

Edit: Here is my working version. I removed the set size so that it downloads those 0 sized files.

```
   ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder builder = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, encoding)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(resource.getMimeType()));
    return builder.body(new InputStreamResource(resource.getContent()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Export** method for downloading google docs or any google files

```
String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.gaertner-servatius.de/images/sinnfrage/kapitel-2/spacetime.gif");
InputStream inStream = url.openStream();
Files.copy(inStream, Paths.get("foobar.gif"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
inStream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Problem persists with thist approach. I tried if export link works and it does when i use it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 com.google.api.services.drive.Drive service;
 static InputStream download(String id)  {
   if (service != null && id != null) try {
     com.google.api.services.drive.model.File gFl =
        service.files().get(id).setFields("downloadUrl").execute();
     if (gFl != null){
       return service.getRequestFactory()
          .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(gFl.getDownloadUrl())).execute().getContent());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
  }
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Google Docs files dont have a downloadUrl. I can get working exportLink, but I cant get it downloaded from code.

Comment: Does it matter if you have the ID (it is a string like 'UW2ablahblaghblahNy00Ums0B1mQ') ?

Comment: I would get the ID (the string) and play with it on the bottom of this [page (Try It!)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list), or [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).